# nUnit3 tests only work with nUnit3 test adapter and not with .net resharper test runner

Tags: .net, nunit, resharper

So I am running nUnit3 tests with the nUnit3 Test Adapter. I tried to run them with resharper test adapter but they all throw exceptions.

What causes problems is: Adding `\\?\` before paths to make long paths viable which is working since .Net 4.6.2. However resharper test runner does not recognize this and gives an `illegal characters in path` exception while nUnit3 Test Adapter works just fine.

How do I fix this?

The line in question is a simple `var baseDir = new DirectoryInfo(path);` in which `path` is a path with `\\?\`.

Comment: Maybe check what .NET Framework ReSharper is running with? See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLrtc.png

Comment: Resharper doesn't show me .net but instead CLR version.